# Is C# namespace separator (.) defined somewhere?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

Full name separator in C# is period character (`.`). e.g. `System.Console.Write`.

Is this defined somewhere like `Path.PathSeperator`, or is it hard coded in .NET reflection classes as well?

(e.g. is `Type.FullName` implemented as `Type.Namespace + "." + Type.Name` assuming that it won't change?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Basically: the language specification. But actually, `Type.FullName` uses the BCL definitions, not the C# definitions - and interestingly *they disagree*. For example:

```
namespace X {
    public class Y {
        public class Z {}
    }
}
```

To C#, `Z` is `X.Y.Z`; to the BCL it is `X.Y+Z`. The representation of generics changes too - with the BCL using back-ticks and numbers rather than angular brackets. I *believe* the BCL uses the CLI's format of types (which has a separate specification), but if you think about it: it is not required to do so (except for during reflection-emit).

AFAIK, these separators are not exposed via anything like `Path.PathSeparator` - but is, as you say, hard coded into the `Type` etc classes.

Comment: I think the `X.Y+Z` notation can be seen for anonymous types and in stack traces...?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar in terms of C#, anonymous types *never have a name*. The compiler generates names that are illegal in C# - things like `<>_4` (etc). You'll only see such notation for anonymous types if looking at their BCL name, perhaps via `.GetType()` - but that is then no different to looking at a regular type like `X.Y+Z`. In terms of stack traces: yes, it'll use the internal representation of types: because again, it isn't the compiler running at that point, so C# terminology does not apply. Similarly, `int` will usually be `System.Int32` etc.

Answer (score 6):

The delimiter between a type and its namespace is defined in the BCL on the [`Type.Delimiter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.delimiter.aspx) field. You'll see this value used in the Reflection APIs and can be reliably used to concatenate a type and its namespace.

Answer (score 2):

According to where [it's used](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/a1b9dd8989d160b8.html) in the reference sources, @Paul's `Type.Delimiter` is the answer to your main question, but the answer to your e.g. is yes, `'.'`, as well as `'+'`, as mentioned in @Marc's answer, is [hard coded](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/775003a4c72f0acc37eab84628fcef541533ba4e/src/vm/typestring.cpp#L347).